# Digit validation in Zend form array notation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, php

I do not know what to write for digits validation in the below code:

```
$row_form = new Zend_Form(array(
        'elements' => array(
            'fldName' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'options'=> array(
                                   'size'=>'15',
                                   'maxlength' => '8',
                                  ),
                'validators'=> array(

                  //Digits Validation

            ) 
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

PS: I want to maintain the array notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row_form = new Zend_Form(array(
        'elements' => array(
            'fldName' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'options'=> array(
                                  'size'=>'15',
                                  'maxlength' => '8',
                                  'validators'=> array('Digits'),
                                  ),

            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

add `array('Digits')` like following

```
'validators'=> array('Digits')
```

Comment: and you can add some message for fail of this validator

Comment: suggest through your answer how should i do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

->setFilters(Array('Digits'));